# spring boot reactive mongo health check doe not show up (reactive mongo)

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, reactive

I am using spring boot 2.0.2 with the reactive mongo driver

As per [Auto-configured HealthIndicators](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#_auto_configured_healthindicators) the mongo health indicator must be autoconfigured. I see rabbit health indicator got autoconfigured

However when I invoke my health actuator the mongo details do not show up.

Here is a snippet of my application.yml

```
management:
    context-path: /acaf/v1
    security:
        enabled: false
    endpoint:
      health:
        show-details: always
    health:
      defaults:
        enabled: true
      mongo:
        enabled: true
```

Here is the output from my actuator:

```
{
    "status": "UP",
    "details": {
        "rabbit": {
            "status": "UP",
            "details": {
                "version": "3.7.5"
            }
        },
        "diskSpace": {
            "status": "UP",
            "details": {
                "total": 250685575168,
                "free": 192069795840,
                "threshold": 10485760
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the [MongoReactiveHealthIndicator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.0.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/mongo/MongoReactiveHealthIndicator.java) was added only in Spring Boot 2.0.4 release, hence my options were:

1. Upgrade to 2.0.4 or
2. Write my own health indicator (I chose this which was just a copy paste of 2.0.4 code)